# Strange SecKeyEncrypt behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rsa

I'm trying to implement RSA encryption with PKCS1 padding using SecKeyEncrypt function.

The code is following:

```
NSData *encryptText(NSString *text, SecKeyRef publicKey)
{
    NSCParameterAssert(text.length > 0);
    NSCParameterAssert(publicKey != NULL);
    NSData *dataToEncrypt = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const uint8_t *bytesToEncrypt = dataToEncrypt.bytes;

    size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
    NSCAssert(cipherBufferSize > 11, @"block size is too small: %zd", cipherBufferSize);

    const size_t inputBlockSize = cipherBufferSize - 11; // since we'll use PKCS1 padding
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * cipherBufferSize);

    NSMutableData *accumulator = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    @try {

        for (size_t block = 0; block * inputBlockSize < dataToEncrypt.length; block++) {
            size_t blockOffset = block * inputBlockSize;
            const uint8_t *chunkToEncrypt = (bytesToEncrypt + block * inputBlockSize);
            const size_t remainingSize = dataToEncrypt.length - blockOffset;
            const size_t subsize = remainingSize < inputBlockSize ? remainingSize : inputBlockSize;

            size_t actualOutputSize = cipherBufferSize;
            OSStatus status = SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey, kSecPaddingPKCS1, chunkToEncrypt, subsize, cipherBuffer, &actualOutputSize);

            if (status != noErr) {
                NSLog(@"Cannot encrypt data, last SecKeyEncrypt status: %ld", status);
                return nil;
            }

            [accumulator appendBytes:cipherBuffer length:actualOutputSize];
        }

        return [accumulator copy];
    }
    @finally {
        free(cipherBuffer);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly on iOS 6, but fails on iOS 5, SecKeyEncrypt returns `-50` (`errSecParam`). It would work on iOS 5 if I change 11 to 12 in `inputBlockSize = cipherBufferSize - 11`.
Apple doc says that input chunk length should be less or equal `SecKeyGetBlockSize() - 11` if PKCS1 padding used. But on iOS 5 it definitely requires shorter input.

My key block size is 64, so input chunk max length is 53, according to docs. On iOS 5 only 52 or less would work.

What's wrong with this code? Or it's iOS 5 Security.framework bug?

**UPD:** problem reproduces only with 512-bit key. Tried with generated 1024-bit key, code works on iOS 5 with `11`

Related Apple doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyEncrypt

Comment: Note to confused cryptographers - the "block size" of the RSA key refers to the byte size of the modulus: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyGetBlockSize

Comment: Please can you add a link to the Apple document you are reading.

Comment: @DuncanJones here it is: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyEncrypt